# Geometry Node : Rotate Instance on Bezier curve according to Tilt in edit mode

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to rotate the instances on a bezier curve according to the tilt on the point of the curve. We can set the tilt using ctrl +t in edit mode.

The  below image is achievable using array modifier and curve modifier along with it. But I want to implement it entirely in Geometry node.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result looks like this:

[image]